# Binding events and border width to the List box Entries

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I thought to bind events to the Listbox entries (members of the Listbox) but I have searched in the document. Haven't got any. But it seems, it is possible since it reacts to a mouse click. Are there any ways to add events to the list box entries?

I tried to add the border width for each item in the Listbox but it says

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bd"
```

I would like to know the possible ways to add a border width to the members of the Listbox.
This code adds the `bg` to the Listbox box entries works even for the `fg` but fails for `bd`

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
class Test(Listbox):
    def __init__(self,p):
        super().__init__(p)
        self.insert(END,'a') 
        self.itemconfig(END,{'bg':'blue','bd':6})
        self.insert(END,'b') 
        self.itemconfig(END,{'bg':'orange'})
        self.insert(END,'c') 
        self.itemconfig(END,{'bg':'red'})
        self.insert(END,'d') 
        self.itemconfig(END,{'bg':'green'})
a=Test(root)
a.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:**

for binding events, I meant events like < Enter > and < Leave >

Comment: You don't "add" events to a listbox, you bind events. The listbox events are documented, and there are many examples on the internet. It's not clear what events you're having problems with.

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry for that. now I have included bd but still, I am getting that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bryan's comment, I came to know that we can't use bd/ bind events for the Listbox elements so I have decided to use a collection of Listboxes where each has a bd and an event bound to it.

In this, I have used canvas+ scrollbar to contain those list boxes. Click on an element to copy its text and hover over it for some effects.

```
from tkinter import *
class LogBox(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,p):
        super().__init__(p)
        self.MFrame=Frame(self)
        self.Vbar=Scrollbar(p,orient=VERTICAL,command=self.yview)
        self.bind('<Configure>',lambda e:self.configure(scrollregion=self.bbox('all')))
        self.bind_all('<MouseWheel>',self.orientScreen)
        self.create_window((0,0),window=self.MFrame,anchor='nw',width=1350)
        self.VFrame=Frame(self.MFrame)
        self.VFrame.pack(fill=X)
        self.config(yscrollcommand=self.Vbar.set)
        self.config(relief=FLAT)
        self.Vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    def append(self,text,color):
        lst=Listbox(self.VFrame,borderwidth=3,height=1,relief=FLAT,font=('helvetica',12,'bold')) # border width thing
        lst.bind('<Enter>',lambda X:self.hover(lst,True)) # for hover effects
        lst.bind('<Leave>',lambda X:self.hover(lst,False))
        lst.insert(END,text)
        lst.config(bg='orange')
        lst.itemconfig(END,{'bg':color})
        lst.pack(fill=X)        
        lst.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',lambda x:self.copy_button(text)) # for click event
    def orientScreen(self,event):
        self.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)),'units')
    def hover(self,lst,status):
        if status:
            lst.config(bg='red',font=('helvetica',15,'bold'))            
        else:
            lst.config(bg='orange',font=('helvetica',12,'bold'))            
    def copy_button(self,text):        
        d = Tk()
        d.withdraw()
        d.clipboard_clear()
        d.clipboard_append(text)
        d.destroy()
if __name__=='__main__':
    root=Tk()
    f=Frame(root)
    b=LogBox(f)
    for i in range(1000):
        b.append(i,'orange')
    b.pack()
    f.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you use labels instead of listboxes?

Comment: @acw1668 I tried that but I found with Listbox it was easier and clean.
since Listbox has two bgs (one for element another for itself) it's easier for me to change the bg of Listbox alone and by default text in Listbox is left-justified (yes seems to be making small diff.)

Comment: A single text widget would probably be easier since you can assign borders and colors to entire lines.

Answer (score 1):

I misspoke in the comment I made earlier, and I apologize for that. You cannot specify a borderwidth for individual items. `itemconfigure` is documented to only accept `background`, `foreground`, `selectbackground`, and `selectforeground`.

As for "adding" events - you can't add events. You can bind to all standard events, and that is documented and works just like for any other widget. In addition, you can bind to `<<ListboxSelect>>` to call a function when the selection changes.

Comment: no, it's my mistake for not specifying details properly.
That's what I wanted to know about the item configure.

for event binding, I want to know is it possible to add the <Enter> event for each list box entries

Comment: @RahulARanger: no, bindings are for widgets, not parts of widgets. However, you can bind to mouse motion and compute which item is under the mouse, and then call any function you want.

Comment: @RahulARanger: how to do what? Bind to mouse motion? There are plenty of examples on the internet, why do you need help?